# wait for element, but element is always present (POM)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm stuck on a issue regards waiting for a element to be visible before clicking it. The problem is that the system that I'm testing all the elements are always visible. Cause the system never change pages just open up pop-up:s. So if I create a wait for element method it will always find the element even when it's in the background of the window that's open at that time.

Have anyone encounter this issue and have a good solution or a code sample I would appreciate it a lot.

EDIT: If I have a pop-up open and I want to go back to the landingpage and calling for the method ClickOnArticleNumber. It will find the xpath before it had time to close to pop-up page and the test will probably fail because it's calling the Click before it's even on the right page.

I hope this will clear up my problem a bit.

```
    public void ClickOnArticleNumber()
    {
        waitForElement(By.XPath("xpath"), 20);
        AddArticleNumber.Click();
    }
```

Kind regards

Robin

Comment: Do you mean that elem, which you want to use, is 'under' a pop-up?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restate what I think I understand to be the issue...

You have a site that has a main page that is always open. Many actions are done in popups... a popup is launched, you do some actions, the popup closes.

The problem comes when you are trying to perform an action on the main page while a popup is closing. The element on the main page is always present and because of that Selenium sees it and attempts the action but that action is blocked by the popup.

Assuming what I stated above is true, you will want to be really crisp when dealing with the popups. When a popup is launched, you will want to wait for the popup to be visible and then perform your actions. When a popup is closed, you will want to wait for some popup-related element to be invisible signaling the popup is no longer visible before attempting actions on the base page.

To do this, you will want to add a wait to every action that triggers the popup to close. I use the page object model so I would do something like this...

Some sample HTML of a popup

```
<div id="actionDialog" ...>
    ...
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

In this HTML we have a popup, the Action Dialog, that has two buttons, the Save and Cancel buttons. Clicking either of these buttons causes the Action Dialog to close so we will want to add a wait after each. Since you are likely to have several buttons that will cause the dialog to close, you create a method that does nothing but waits for the dialog to close so it can be easily called from the other methods and stores the "wait for close" logic in one place.

In the page object for the ActionDialog, I would have a few methods: one to wait for the dialog to close and a couple others to click the save or cancel buttons.

```
private By actionDialogLocator = By.Id("actionDialog");
private By cancelButtonLocator = By.Id("cancel");
private By saveButtonLocator = By.Id("save");

public void Cancel()
{
    Driver.FindElement(cancelButtonLocator).Click();
    WaitForDialogToClose();
}
public void Save()
{
    Driver.FindElement(saveButtonLocator).Click();
    WaitForDialogToClose();
}
private void WaitForDialogToClose()
{
    new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(actionDialogLocator));
}
```

Now when you call `Click()` or `Save()`, the script will wait for the dialog to close, preventing the next call to some element on the main page from failing because the dialog will be closed before that action is attempted.